# Parsley.js - Password Validation doesnt submit

Tags: javascript, php, validation, passwords, parsley.js

i have a problem with parsley.js. every time i hit the submit button it doesnt do anything.
does anyone know a solution for this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Registrierung</title>

<link href="bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>   
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-3.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/parsley.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/parsley.messages.de.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="body">

<?php
$fpw="";
?>
<div class="container">
<div class="offset4">
<div>
<h1>Registrierung</h1>
<?php if($fpw == true) echo '<div class="error" Passwörter stimmen nicht überein!<br></div>'; ?>
<form method="post" action="aregistrierung.php" data-validate="parsley">

<label for="passwort1" class="labbel">Passwort</label>
<input id="passwort1" name="passwort1" type="password" data-type="password" data-required="true" placeholder="Passwort" />

<label for="passwort2" class="labbel">Passwort bestätigen</label>
<input id="passwort2" name="passwort2" type="password" data-type="password" data-required="true" placeholder="Passwort" data-equalto="#passwort1" data-equalto-message="Passwort stimmt nicht überein"/>

<br><br>
<input name="registrieren" type="submit" value="Registrieren" class="btn btn-large btn-success"/>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i edited the whole file into it; i have tested it with a fake link like "sadfgkfe.php"  too, it doesnt gave me the "not found" error.

Comment: Can you post content of `registrierung.php` ?

Comment: What is `data-validate`?

Comment: edited the whole file in the post @Paul; data-validate triggers the parsley data validation (and not the HTML5 one)

Comment: Is there any errors in your `error console`? http://ggnome.com/wiki/Using_The_Browser_Error_Console

Comment: firebug says: class="parsley-validated parsley-error" (at both password inputs, instead of: class="parsley-validated parsley-success") but i dont know what it caused. @Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Doodlebot said, use `parsley-validate` on the form.

Remove `data-type="password"` - parsley has no password validation.

Change the `data-` prefix to `parsley-`.

[Here is a sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WaNvC/2/).

Comment: parsley doesnt do anything when i use your fiddle... in fact the only way it validates is when i am using data-validation="parsley" (exept for the password one); my sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/53RWg/2/

Comment: Well, what can I say, I run my fiddle, I put in two different passwords, press the "Registrieren" button and I get the message "Passwort stimmt nicht überein".
I'm using Chrome, but I can't see why it wouldn't work for you.
**Has anyone else tried the fiddle?**

Comment: would it be too much to ask you for your complete folder, uploaded somewhere (dropbox, google,..)? its not that i dont believe you, i just cant find the problem...

Comment: Here is your fiddle "fixed": http://jsfiddle.net/53RWg/3/   You need jQuery as a framework. You need Parsley.js as a resource. You need to remove the `data-type="password"` clauses. I set the namespace to `data-parsley-` which should be HTML5 compliant.

Comment: oh god, my parsley.js was corrupt/not working correctly... i feel so ashamed, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the form attribute data-validate="parsley" with parsley-validate and replace data-required="true" with required.

Comment: did it, but parsley doesnt validate then (HTML5 validation does)